# Matlab Recreating freqz, normalizing x axis and getting half of plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a function which is basically recreating the freqz command in matlab. I have figured out how to plot the entire transform of my frequency response, but I only need half of it, and I need to normalize it from pi to 1 (where 0:pi represents my x axis, and I want that to go to 0:1). The code is here:

```
function freqrespplot(b, a)

hb = fft(b,512);
ha = fft(a,512);

magh = (abs(hb) ./ abs(ha));
angh = angle(hb ./ ha);

x = linspace(0,2*pi, 512);

subplot(2,1,1);
plot(x,magh,'g');
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(x,angh,'r');

end
```

In the example of b = [1 2 2], a = [0 1 .8], plots like the following:

freqrespplot([1 2 2], [0 1 .8]);
Magnitude
[image: Correct total Magnitude, want 0 to pi normalized 0 to 1]

and my corresponding phase plot is
[image: Want phase 0 to pi and normalized 0 to 1]

I want the x-axis (omega) to go from 0 to 1 in both cases, and correspond to 0 to pi by taking only half of the graph, like this if possible:

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: What's wrong with replotting it yourself using custom x axis coordinates and cropping the y-data?

Comment: Please also post sample input data or a toy example to help recreate your plots.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the normalized 0:1 x-axis from my data without simply resizing the plot (squishing it horizonally along the axis). What I'd like to be able to do is only look at 0 to pi of the current picture and set that on a normalized axis. Sample input data posted, thanks for that heads-up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need some small changes, marked with comments in the code below:

```
function freqrespplot(b, a)

hb = fft(b,512);
ha = fft(a,512);

magh = (abs(hb) ./ abs(ha));
angh = angle(hb ./ ha);

x = linspace(0,2, 513); %// 2, not 2*pi. And 513. Last value will be discarded
x = x(1:end-1); %// discard last value to avoid having 0 and 2*pi (they are the same)

subplot(2,1,1);
plot(x(1:end/2),magh(1:end/2),'g'); %// plot only half
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(x(1:end/2),angh(1:end/2),'r'); %// plot only half

end
```

With your example `b` and `a` this produces

[image]

You may want to include one additional sample to reach the right edge of the graph. I comment only differences with the above code:

```
function freqrespplot(b, a)

hb = fft(b,512);
ha = fft(a,512);

magh = (abs(hb) ./ abs(ha));
angh = angle(hb ./ ha);

x = linspace(0,2, 513);
x = x(1:end-1);

subplot(2,1,1);
plot(x(1:end/2+1),magh(1:end/2+1),'g'); %// plot only lower half plus one value
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(x(1:end/2+1),angh(1:end/2+1),'r'); %// plot only lower half plus one value

end
```

Compare the resulting graph (rightmost part):

[image]

Comment: Firstly, thank you for explaining it so well! I see now that it actually only had to deal with the formatting of the axis. Is the reason for going from 0 to 2 in linspace because that's the way of normalizing the figure?

Comment: I think my biggest matlab problem overall has been getting used to using vectors, so I see that this translated into this function also. I'll have to do additional research to fix this.

Comment: @Mikael_SFSU Please see edit: I've added a second version including one additional sample, so that the graph reaches the vertical line at x=1. And yes, you basically use `linspace` from 0 to 2 so that the half value is 1, not pi